# Accessing a div tag from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am Working in asp.net and c#. I have a `div` tag in my application with `class="something"`.I need to access this **something** class in codebehind.How can i do that..

**Code**:

```
 <div class="something">
//somecode
 <div>
```

**Note**:I want access **Something** class in codebehind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Give `ID` and attribute `runat='server'` as :

```
<div class="something" ID="mydiv" runat="server">
//somecode
<div>
```

Codebehind:

You can modify your **`something`** styles here.

```
mydiv.Style.Add("display", "none");
```

Comment: I have this on my .aspx page: `<div id="content" style="text-align: center;" runat="server"></div>`. When I access it from code-behind: `content.Visible = false;` I receive the following error: `The name 'content' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: @SiKni8 That's my problem too. This is not the answer as it assumes the DIV is inside the HTML page. What about master pages, content place holders, etc

Comment: The "id" we gave from markup, does not shown on code page.

Answer (score 4):

Make it a server tag if you want to access it in CS code.

```
<div class="something" runat="server" id="something">
//somecode
 <div>
```

asp.net does not provide a method to search by classes. so you will have to rely on the ID.

CS:

```
something.InnerHtml = "some code";
```

Comment: you can use an alternative written in my answer

Comment: Once marked as a server tag, you can use the id directly. Added a CS snippet. Should give you access to the properties you can change.

Comment: You cannot access a <DIV> with intellisense if it's inside a content place holder or a gridview. So no these answers are not answers

Answer (score 3):

You need the runat='server' attribute and ID.

```
<div class="something" runat="server" id="TestDiv">
//somecode
<div>
```

Then in code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TestDiv.InnerHtml += "test"; // The div is accessible
}
```

Comment: I have this on my .aspx page: `<div id="content" style="text-align: center;" runat="server"></div>`. When I access it from code-behind: `content.Visible = false;` I receive the following error: `The name 'content' does not exist in the current context`

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that may help solve some of the issues encountered by others in the comments of the selected answer would be to use the Control class with the FindControl() method to access the desired element.

For example:

```
Control myDiv = (Control)FindControl("myDiv");

myDiv.Visible = false;
```

I found this to be quite effective, hopefully it can help someone else out.

Answer (score 0):

All you can do is to loop through all controls and then check if its `CssClass` is `something`

i.e. if that div is inside a the div with ID `Div1` then you will use:

```
foreach (Control c in Div1.Controls)
{
    if (c.CssClass == "something")
    {
        // do the moves here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

div tag is for making your page stylish.you can use id & class attributes within div and this id & class name will call on css & js

Answer (score -3):

protected void Datalist_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
        {
 System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div22 = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("something");
}