# How to use dictionary in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Q1:Capital of India--
(A)New Delhi(B)Mumbai(C)Kolkatta(D)Lucknow.(these option belongs to list item)
Q2:Which one is programming language---
(A)C(B)Hindi(C)English(D)French.(these option belongs to list item)
Q3:Who is the current CEO of Microsoft corporation---
(A)Nadella(B)Billgate(C)Sikka(D)None of these.(these option belongs to list item)

here i am asking to get result in a single click in asp.net C#.
i want to use this method for offline Exam .
thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is very unclear. Please post some example code.

Comment: you mean multiple choice questions, and you want one to be selected at a time. if iam not wrong @Sudhakar

Comment: So, is this an example of completing all multiple choice questions and clicking a submit button at the end? Presumably you're then trying to store the chosen option for each question into an array or something?

Comment: are you using win forms or xaml wpf for UI?

Comment: @DeshDeepSingh you are right , suppose we have 10 question and each question has four option and asking for all attempted(selected option) questions answer in one click .

Comment: so you want me to code to choose only one out of four or take the selected solutions from all at the time of submit? Also edit your question and frame it properly Please.

Comment: @sr28, i think you understand the question so please help me , how can i code for that.

Comment: @DeshDeepSingh, Yes, suggest a code for this action.

Comment: Wait Ill just create and example for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably contain all the radio button lists for the various questions within a panel to make it easier to only loop through these rather than any other radio button lists you may have on the page. I would then do something like this for the single button click event:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Store the question number and answer.
    Dictionary<int, string> Answers = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    //Loop through the radio button lists within your panel
    int i = 1; //used to determine the question number
    foreach (var rdbl in MyPanel.Controls.OfType<RadioButtonList>())
    {
        Answers.Add(i, rdbl.SelectedValue.ToString());
        i++;
    }

    //Do something with your stored answers.
}
```

I've not tested this code so let me know how you get on with it. Also, it would be easier to make this more specific to your scenario if you were to post your aspx code that you have.

***UPDATE***

To reference your div tag in the code behind (instead of using MyPanel) you need to make sure the div looks something like this:

```
<div ID="MyDiv" runat="server">
```

This should allow you to reference the div in the code behind simply by using 'MyDiv'. See [here for further examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930785/accessing-a-div-tag-from-codebehind).

Comment: how we can store answers in dictionary, please help.

Comment: @Sudhakarsingh - the code I supplied above creates a Dictionary called 'Answers'. I've assumed you will put all your questions within a panel (which I called 'MyPanel') on your aspx page. By looping through all of your radio button lists I then add the question number (i) and the selected value using Answers.Add(i, rdbl.SelectedValue.ToString()). What issue are you having with the above code?

Comment: i am not using a panel , my code in .aspx page in div tag , so how can i overcome this issue?

Comment: @Sudhakarsingh give the div tag an Id property and a 'runat=server' property. Then replace the 'MyPanel' bit in my code with the id you've given to the div tag.

Comment: here i am confusing with answers as dictionary<int, string>(); and declared rdbl variable.

Comment: @Sudhakarsingh - the Dictionary called Answers is where you will store each question number and the answer selected for it. You get this information for the dictionary from each of the rdbl variables (implied to be radio button list) in the collection of radio button lists within your div. So you set up a dictionary for the info you want, then loop through each of your radio button lists in your div, and at each stage add the question number and the selected value. Does that help?

Comment: @Sudhakarsingh - once you've stored all the question and answer information into the dictionary you can do what you want with it, such as work out a score, save it to a database etc.

Comment: now error is that your div id not exist in current context, i also used extension of system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.

Comment: @Sudhakarsingh - did you add the id and runat=server properties to your div? If so and you can't reference your div by it's id in the code behind then try using FindControl like this Control MyDiv = FindControl("Your control id here"); Then replace MyPanel with MyDiv in my code.

Comment: -i already use runat server that you already suggested.

Comment: @Sudhakarsingh - did you try FindControl?

Comment: ,can you write a code to do something with stored answers? and stored answers not in database i strictly want to store them in webpage is it possible?

Comment: @Sudhakarsingh - that's not really how SO works. If this code now works for you and it solves your initial problem then it should be marked as the answer. As I'm not involved with building your application I can't tell you what to do with your stored answers. That's something you'll need to work out. For example are you hoping to display their score, or do some calculations based off them, or tailor another pages content based off them? These are the questions you need to figure out. If you run into problems then write another question.

Comment: @Sudhakarsingh -  did this code help fix your initial problem?